# Example of statistical experiment in which the statistical unit is time

Tags: descriptive-statistics, terminology, definition

Could you give me some examples of statistical experiment/analysis in which the statistical unit is
the time? If I conduct a study on the number of people who have attended a bachelor degree over time, is my statistical unit the time?

During a statistical course my Professor said something like that, and now I am not completely sure to know properly the meaning of "statistical unit".

Comment: "Unit" has multiple meanings. In one context it can be a dimension of measurement like seconds or meters. In the statistical context, a "statistical unit" represents a member of a population being studied. Time is a dimension of measurement, but I don't see how it could be interpreted in the statistical sense as a member of a population. It seems like you're conflating "unit" with "statistical unit".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, consider making it as an answer. As I said in my earlier comment (deleted), I have not found a frequent usage of the term, albeit in sample survey (cf. Cochran), the author interchangeably used _sampling units/units_.

Comment: If you use "year started particular course at particular college" as a [statistical unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_unit), you might  look at how many there were in total and how many had a job five years later, for various courses and colleges.  You might find those in "class of 2001" tended to do better than those in "class of 2004" for those you had data (perhaps due to the global financial crisis in 2008), and conclude that you believed something similar was likely to have happened in other colleges.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, interesting, after your answer I found that, which metch all the two definitions... https://www.insee.fr/en/metadonnees/definition/c1528